# Why is it a syntax error to use explicit object parameters in a function pointer?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++23, explicit-object-parameter

So I've run into a problem when trying to use explicit object parameters for a function pointer, for a project I'm working on.
The code at a glance seems syntactically fine but as this is a new feature which I can't find too much information online, I am at a loss as to why I get random syntax errors.
Specifically the error is "syntax error: ')'"

My only real guess is that it's some sort of MSVC incompleteness/bug in which case I will probably have to switch to a different compiler.

```cpp
///base.h
///...
#include <map>

template <class s>
using FunctionMap = std::map<std::string,void(*)(this s& self)>;
                                            ///^ Syntax Error Here

class base{
//...
public:
   ///Get Map of fPtr
   template <class Self>
   FunctionMap<Self>* get_scripts(this const Self& self);
}
```

I expected this to compile but it keeps on coming up with the syntax error. I know explicit object parameters are only partially implemented in MSVC.

Comment: This has nothing to do with deduced this. A deduced this is just a specialized a kind of a template. It appears that the shown code attempts to declare a map containing a signature with a deduced this, i.e. a template. You cannot store templates in containers. C++ does not work this way, on a fundamental level. You'll run into the same problem attempting to declare a `std::map<std::string, template<typename ptr> x>`. It's unclear what the attempted goal of the shown code is, but whatever it is, a completely different approach will be needed.

Comment: "this" is a variable not a type.  You don't put variables in types unless you're decltype-ing with it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Explicit object parameters in function pointers make no sense.
This is not an MSVC issue, it's simply not valid code.
A free function pointer cannot have any object parameter, be that implicit or explicit.

However, note the following:

- `void(*)(s& self)` would be just fine, without the `this`
- taking the address of an [explicit object member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Explicit_object_member_functions) yields a regular function pointer

  - e.g. `&base::get_scripts<T>` is of type `std::map<...>(*)(s&)`

In short, you can just use regular function pointers.
Simply get rid of the `this` in the function pointer type.

Answer (score 2):

An explicit object parameter is a concept that is meaningful *only* to a member function (specifically, it means that you can use them with member function call syntax, like `m.func()` or similar, and the given object will be transformed into the explicit object parameter). Once that member function gets converted to a function pointer, all of the magic of having an "explicit object parameter" goes away. It's *just* a function pointer; the first parameter has no special powers and there's no special call syntax that you can use with it.

The function pointer's signature is what you'd get if you remove `this` from the member function's signature.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use [explicit object parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Explicit_object_parameter) in a free function because it just wouldn’t make sense (what will **this** be deduced to then)?

```
template <class s>
using FunctionMap = std::map<std::string, void(*)(this s& self)>; <——- pointer to free function stored in an std::map.
```

But **deducing this** will make more sense here:

```
class base{
//...
public:
   ///Get Map of fPtr
   template <class Self>
   FunctionMap<Self>* get_scripts(this const Self& self); <——- makes sense here doesn’t it? this is deduced to base.
}
```

And if:

```
class derived : public base {} <——- this is deduced to derived.
```

Comment: I know no one asked but just in case: ***”A pointer to a member function with explicit object parameter is an ordinary pointer to function, not a pointer to member”***